# react - feature flags returns error "export 'useFeatureFlag' was not found in 'react-feature-flags'

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use feature flags in react.  but when i try to use my react webpart i see the error:

> "export 'useFeatureFlag' was not found in 'react-feature-flags'

Here's the relevant code:

**Test.tsx file:**

```
import featureFlags from "../../../featureflags.json"; 
import { useFeatureFlag } from 'react-feature-flags'; 

const { isTestControlEnabled} = useFeatureFlag('testControl', featureFlags);

           <div className={styles.stepDivider} />
        {this.props.controlTestComponent  && isTestControlEnabled  && (
          <>
            <StepComponent
              iconName={"Sampler"}
```

When I try to use the web part, I see the following error in the console:

> Warning - [webpack] 'dist':
> ./lib/webparts/widgets/components/TestComponent.js 21:34-48 "export
> 'useFeatureFlag' was not found in 'react-feature-flags'

This is the version I"m using:

```
widget-components@0.0.1 /Users/me/src/projects/widget-components
└── react-feature-flags@1.0.0
```

Comment: It appears that package has no export named `useFeatureFlag` https://github.com/romaindso/react-feature-flags/blob/master/src/index.js . Were you following some article or video that led you to expect it?

Comment: yeah.  Chat GPT.  lol. I'm not a react developer.   Can you point me in the right direction?  I need a package that will read the flags from a json file.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Your current approach probably needs to be abandoned entirely, because chat gpt just picked a library with a vaguely correct sounding name which hasn't been updated in 6 years and invented code that doesn't exist.

Comment: You've imported the json file, can you not use that directly? eg, `if (featureFlags.testControl) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: yep.  i've tried using the variable directly. that works.  but i wanted to find a lib so that i'm not reinventing the wheel.  and if in future we want to use more advanced features, we can.  Like. in .net core they have feature filters etc.  But if that's not the case... I guess i can just stick to the json file alone.

Comment: I'll abandon the sample (broken) code and just stick to the json file alone.  Thanks @NicholasTower.  Upvoting your comment.

Comment: Please use ChatGPT for what it was intended for -- INSPIRATION and not GOSPEL --  You still need to know the fundamentals.

Comment: @dot Beware that the package `react-feature-flags` looks outdated. For example, it declares React 16.3 as a peer dependency and uses class based components (pre hooks era).

Comment: Thanks @YuryTarabanko.  I'm just using a simple json file now with the flags inside.  I've abandoned that package / the entire approach.  Thanks for the note.  In this particular case, it seems Chat GPT led me down a useless path!  Doesn't help that I've never used react either.  but thanks again!